# Vikings weren't who we thought they were

Tags: grammar

How do you analyse "who" in the following sentence?

> Vikings weren't who we thought they were

Comment: What do you not understand about "who"? What do you think it means?

Comment: When can it serve as a fused relative?

Comment: You're an experienced enough user that you ought to know the bare question that you've asked here doesn't cut it. I've closed it for "*Please edit to **add the research** you have done in your efforts to answer the question, or **provide more context.***", but it could equally be flagged for *Needs details or clarity*. When you've improved the question to minimal standards, I'll happy reopen it. I'll also be able to understand what you're looking for without a back-and-forth in the comments section, so I'll give it a solid answer too, if I'm able.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm content with  Jack O'Flaherty  discussing the issue with me. He knows enough about it to need no introduction to background research..

Comment: If someone needs to have background information explained to them to participate in the thread, they are probably not qualified to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

In *who we thought they were*, *who* is the idea that we had about the identity of the Vikings. Someone is probably about to tell use what was wrong about our idea.

Compare:
You thought this was an authentic Rolex, but it is not *what* you thought it was. It's a knockoff.

Comment: The use of "what" in your sentence is natural; it is a free relative pronoun (equal to a sequence of antecedent and "which"/"that"). However, "who" in the OP example is curious. If it is also a free relative pronoun, can it occur in "I gave the book to who knew the answer." If not, why?

Comment: The use of *who*  in the *Vikings aren't who...* is also natural. The antecedent isn't stated there, but it is implied in *who we thought they were*. In my example, you can drop the explicitly stated antecedent and say as a sentence *This is not what you thought it was.* In your new example, which puts a clause as the object of a preposition, not linked by *to be*, you need a word such as *one* or *those* before *who*. I can't explain why,

Comment: That's why I  find the use of "who" puzzling. I'm trying to find examples where such a free relative use of "who" does NOT occur after copular BE.

Comment: How about the following? "John is not regarded as who we used to think he was" and "John is not considered (to be) who we used to think he was"?

Comment: Both of those are so awkward that I wouldn't use them. "Free relative" seems to also be called "fused relative clause", where the antecedent and the pronoun are fused into one word. Note that your example "I gave the book to *whoever* knew the answer." is grammatical when modified with "whoever". According to this link, the use of *who* is very limited in fused relatives: https://tinyurl.com/2699ktsc

Comment: Apparently, in the first example of the Vikings, the *who* clause is an interrogative, not a fused relative. Here is another link: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4665  which seems to suggest that the rules about using *who* as a fused relative are in flux. I note also that there are a number of stackexchange ELL and ELU discussions of the subject. I'm tired and going to bed, so I'll leave it at that!

Comment: Here is an ELU discussion of fused vs interrogative: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124273/fused-relatives-versus-interrogatives

Comment: I think the "who" in the Vikings example is a fused relative, because the sentence is paraphrasable as "Vikings weren't the kind of people (that) we thought they were," where "the kind of people" and the relative pronoun can be fused into "who."  On the other hand, an interrogative would refer to information or a question, such as "Who the Vikings robbed back then is difficult to answer, (= The question of who the Vikings . . . is difficult to answer)."

Comment: To me, it seems like an interrogative. The implied question is *who were the Vikings?*, and the corresponding information (claimed to be incorrect) is the idea we had about them.

Comment: Here's my rationale. An interrogative would be equal to "the question of WH" or "the answer to the question of WH." However, Viking were not a question or an answer to a question.

Comment: I'll just repeat that I disagree. Time for bed.